# How to test the battery drain and frame rendering in iOS applications similar to pCloudy for Android?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

We have a popular tool called as pCloudy for testing the Android battery drain for Android applications as shown below :

https://www.pcloudy.com/android-app-testing-for-battery-drain/

Since pCloudy doesnt have support for iOS applications for checking the Battery Drain and Frame rate. Please help me with another alternatives which support testing Battery Drain and Frame rate for the iOS applications.